# Homepage is not mobile friendly according to Google, other pages are

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, responsiveness

I have a strange error. For a client I added some mobile CSS for the website to be responsive: http://www.sixsigma.nl. When checking the website on Google, it says the homepage is NOT mobile friendly, while other pages are: http://www.sixsigma.nl/artikelen

I have checked all the mark-up, but as far as I can see all is correct. I have actually cross referenced this with another site in which i also implemented responsive CSS, and all is the same. I have tried to remove tracking script that were blocked from crawling, media, css and js are allowed in robots.txt. I can not find the error.

How is this possible and how can I make Google see the homepage as mobile friendly?

Comment: My first hunch is to check if it's related to the twitter feed / widgets on your  home page. Easy enough to check by temporarily disabling them

Answer (score 0):

I would start by lowering your image quality on the homepage for mobile devices, your page is loading at 2.1 mb which is way too high, where as your other sites only load at 1mb (which is still on the high side). Try adjusting your image sizes first.

600kb is a good target for mobile devices.